# C# Cache of Object is quoting strings

Tags: caching, c#-4.0

That's something I can't believe, but it's happening.

I have the following code:

```
public class UserData
{
  public string displayname;
  public int age;
}

UserData ud = new UserData();
ud.displayname = "bar";
ud.age = 2;

HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("foo", ud, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

UserData lud = HttpContext.Current.Cache["foo"];

HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("displayname",ud.displayname);
```

Guess what is the output?

```
"bar"
```

Quoted!!!!
*(The int field is not affected, it returned as int, not quoted, etc...)*

Why is that? I searched on MSDN and google to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ashx page to see the output.